# Set button position programmatically with auto-layout

Tags: ios7, uibutton, xcode5, autolayout

Depending on an if statement I want to change the position of a button programmatically, with auto-layout ON. Heres what I was doing before auto-layout, and I not sure why it isn't working when I turn on auto layout.

```
if ([dayString isEqualToString:@"Wednesday"]) {

      [Btn setFrame:CGRectMake(20,49,135,35)];
}
else {
    [Btn setFrame:CGRectMake(49,49,135,35)];
}
```

Thanks for the help. I really appreciate it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's simple. Auto Layout and frame-setting are opposites. If you're using auto layout, it is auto layout that sets the frames of things, not you.

To be more precise: You *can* set the frame, but when auto layout comes along and lays things out, its sets the frame according to the constraints. Thus, your changes are being overridden.

Thus, one option is to manipulate, in code, the constraints that are positioning the button.

Alternatively, what you might want to do in this case is take the button out of the storyboard and create it in code and put it into your interface. When you do that, the button is not under the influence of auto layout and you can just set the frame.

Comment: So how would I go about setting the location of a button with auto-layout with an if statement? Or can you not do that?

Comment: You'd change / set the constraints. Alternatively, you could make arrangements to "protect" this button from being affected by auto layout, but that's more elaborate.

Comment: I do this in the storyboard? or can it be done in a .m

Comment: There is no code (no if) in a storyboard! If you want to change where this thing is in code, you must change its constraints, not its frame.

Comment: So just to clarify, if I want to change the position of a button depending on the day, I cannot use auto-layout?

Comment: Just to clarify, yes of course you can. But you will do it by manipulating constraints, not frame.

Comment: Constraints are things (objects). You can manipulate them in code. So, this button is being positioned by some constraints. You can change them. You can remove them and replace them with other constraints. This will cause the button to be put in a different place (by auto layout).

Comment: Or create the button in code, not in the storyboard. That takes it out of the influence of auto layout, and now you can set its frame.

Comment: Here's a code example where I reposition a view in two ways: one using its frame, the other using constraints: https://github.com/mattneub/Programming-iOS-Book-Examples/blob/master/bk2ch06p255rotationChangesInterface/ch19p593rotationChangesInterface/ViewController.m